# Executing masonry after cycle

Tags: javascript, reload, cycle

Can't seem to get my images re-ordered after clicking the image to display the following.

However when I resize my browser the images do re-order properly.

I've tried so much but I'm stuck, I just want to fire the masonry again after clicking for the next image.

[link to website](http://degrafischeprofeet.be/website/index2.html)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){

    $('#container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: 20,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
      isFitWidth: true
    });

  });
</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#projectslide').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  0, 
        next:   '#projectslide',
        timeout: 0,
        fit: 1,
        slideResize: 1,
        reshape: 1,
    });
});

    $('#container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: 20,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
      isFitWidth: true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of the Cycle plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) the author shows how to define callback functions, so you can do something like this:

$('#projectslide').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  0, 
        next:   '#projectslide',
        timeout: 0,
        fit: 1,
        slideResize: 1,
        reshape: 1,
        **after: function() {
                $('#container').masonry('reload');
        }**
    });